# Mapbox Android expressions issue

Tags: android, expression, mapbox

I'm new to Mapbox and want to change color of selected Feature. I implement this with Mapbox example with adding new field "SELECTED" like this:

```
//For deselect all
 for (Feature feature : featureCollection.features()) {
            feature.properties().addProperty("SELECTED", false);
        }

Feature feature = featureCollection.features().get(index);
feature.properties().addProperty("SELECTED", true);
```

Now specific field "SELETCED" is exists. But i can not how to say: If it is "true" use this color for `fillExtrusionColor` else use another color.

```
style.addLayer(new FillExtrusionLayer(
                    activeLayerId, sourceId).withProperties(
                    fillExtrusionHeight(20f),
                    fillExtrusionColor(get("FILL_COLOR")),
                    fillExtrusionOpacity(0.7f)
            ));
```

I googled and find that i should Use Expressions for this purpos but could not find out how!

Comment: You spelled "SELECTED" wrong three times.. Is your code correct?

Comment: @philoez98 I type here again so it was mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do what you are asking:

```
fillExtrusionColor(match(get("SELECTED"),
          true, get("FILL_COLOR"), // if true use this color
          false, rgba(0, 0, 255.0f, 1.0f),
          get("FILL_COLOR"))) // default color to use
```

or:

```
fillExtrusionColor(switchCase(
  eq(get("SELECTED"), true), get("FILL_COLOR"), // if SELECTED == true use this color
  eq(get("SELECTED"), false), rgba(0, 0, 255.0f, 1.0f),
  get("FILL_COLOR")))) // default value
```

You can learn more [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/expressions/).